# How to update multiple rows with form data

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

Ok so I have been working with this for a total of 3 hours and I just cannot figure out what to do.

Here is my form

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="po[]" value="<?php echo $ord['id'] ?>" /><input id="acts" value='1' type="checkbox" <?php echo $check ?> name="acts[]" /></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $pnme['icon'] ?>" style="height: 25px; width: 25px; vertical-align: middle;" /><?php echo $pnme['name'] ?></td>
    <td><input id="per" style="background: #BDBDBD; width: 100px;" name="per[]" size="5" type="text" class="small" value="<?php echo $ord['fee'] ?>" /></td>
    <td><input id="dol" style="background: #BDBDBD; width: 100px;" name="dol[]" size="5" type="text" class="small" value="<?php echo $ord['cost'] ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

Once the form is submitted it will be sending more than one value per key, I was going to try just to take each and put them in an array and then use a foreach statement but since I have 4 different key's with multiple values I have no clue how to combine them.

This is what I have to get my different arrays for each multi-key

```
$po = array($_GET['po']);

$fee = array($_GET['per']);

$co = array($_GET['dol']);

$act = array($_GET['acts']);
```

Basically I am trying to achieve this

```
$db->query("UPDATE `exchange` SET `fee` = '" . $per . "' AND `cost` = '" . $co . "' AND `active` = '" . $act . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $po . "'");
```

for each.

maybe I am trying to do this in a much more complicated manner than what is actually needed. I am running on little sleep and have exhausted myself just trying to complete this one what should be simple task.

If I could get a point in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `if loop` works with what I am trying to succeed here, I am not saying that it is the proper way, but it does the job

```
    $po = implode(",", $_POST['po']);
    $po = explode(",", $po);

    $fee = implode(",", $_POST['per']);
    $fee = explode(",", $fee);

    $co = implode(",", $_POST['dol']);
    $co = explode(",", $co);

    $act = implode(",", $_POST['acts']);
    $act = explode(",", $act);
    print_r($act);
    for ($i = 0; ; $i++) {
    if ($i > count($po) - 1) {
        break;
    }
```